# Android Paint breakText new line

Tags: java, android, newline, paint

I use `Paint.breakText()` to get the linecount. But it seems that it won't work for '\n'.

```
text = "a\n";
int lineCount = 0;
int index = 0;
int length = text.length();
//maxWidthPX is 240
while(index < length - 1) {
    index += paint.breakText(text, index, length, true, maxWidthPX, null);
    lineCount++;
}
```

It was supposed that lineCount is 2.
But it turn out that lineCount is 1.
Shouldn't it be 2? Cause text contain a new line separator : '\n'.

[AndroidStudio debug break](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI9Ri.png)

Comment: Your length is 2. You are looping until  lower than length -1 (so 1). You will only enter the loop once, hence incrementing lineCount once.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official document paint.breakText() requires following parameters:

```
public int breakText(CharSequence text, int start, int end, boolean measureForwards, float maxWidth, float[] measuredWidth)
```

So, it breaks the character sequence from start to end position given by you where you wrote:

```
paint.breakText(text, index, length, true, maxWidthPX, null);
```

where,  **end = length**

That's why, it always executes once!

I have edited your code:

```
text = "a\n";
int lineCount = 0;
int index = 0;
int length = text.length();
//maxWidthPX is 240
while(index <= length - 1) {
    index += paint.breakText(text, index, index + 1, true, maxWidthPX, null);
    lineCount++;
}
```

And, found lineCount is 2.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I found a solution by using String split()

```
        String[] textStr = text.split("\\n");
    int allLineCount = 0;
    for (String textTmp : textStr) {
        int lineCount = 0;
        int index = 0;
        int length = textTmp.length();

        while (index < length - 1) {
            index += paint.breakText(textTmp, index, length, true, maxWidthPX, null);
            lineCount++;
        }
        allLineCount += lineCount;
    }
```